# What elements does a map of rings fix if both rings contain the same algebraically closed field as a subring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, ring-homomorphism

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Let $R,S$ be rings such that $R,S$ both contain $k$ as a subring. Let $\varphi:R\to S$ be a ring homomorphism. Then does $\varphi(a)=a$ for all $a\in k$?

So far I think: $\varphi:R\to S$ is a ring homomorphism $\implies \varphi|_{k}:k\to k$ is a field homomorphism $\implies \varphi(1_{k})=1_{k}$.

But I think this only shows that $\varphi$ fixes elements of $k$ generated by $1_{k}$. So let's say $k$ is $\mathbb{C}$ (I don't know any other algebraically closed field). Then I reckon that this would imply $\varphi$ fixes $\mathbb{Z}$ (and by the answer I got from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3069325/why-must-an-automorphism-of-an-extension-of-mathbbq-send-1-to-a-rational-nu), $\mathbb{Q}$ as well), but I don't know what I can say about irrational or imaginary numbers.

Comment: Choose $R=S=k=\Bbb C$ and consider $\varphi(z)=\bar z$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but a question, can we have a homomorphism (besides the one that maps $z$ to $z$) not defined this way? So can something that sends $z$ to something besides $\overline{z}$ still be a homomorphism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case where all the rings are $\mathbb C$ is already interesting enough! As Berci mentioned in the comments, conjugation gives an example of an automorphism that only fixes the reals. One can show that this is the only non-trivial automorphism fixing the reals.

To answer your second question in the comments:
Assuming choice, there are even more exotic counterexamples, so called *wild automorphisms*.
You might find the discussion on [this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/412010/wild-automorphisms-of-the-complex-numbers) interesting.

Comment: I see, thanks for your answer. I didn't know that it would be so "wild" to have an automorphism besides the identity/conjugation, lol!